# why can not the controller of the required directive be found in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote two directives in angularjs, one is embedded in the other one.

below is the scripts for the directives:

```
module.directive('foo', [
   '$log', function($log) {
     return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div id="test" ng-transclude></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope;
        return $scope.panes = [];
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        return $log.log('test1', scope.panes);
      }
    };
  }
]);

module.directive('bar', [
  '$log', function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      require: '^?foo',
      controller: function($scope) {
        return this.x = 1;
      },
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
        return $log.log('test2', fooCtrl);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

below is the piece of html:

```
<foo ng-controller="IndexController">
      <bar></bar>
    </foo>
```

below is the element generated, inspected from the chrome developer tools

```
<div id="test" ng-transclude="" ng-controller="IndexController" class="ng-scope">
      <div ng-transclude="" class="ng-scope"></div>
    </div>
```

below is chrome console output:

```
test2 
Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
 angular.js:5930
test1 
Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
```

**Question:**
The child directive can not get the parent directive's controller, so the fourth parameter "fooCtrl" for link function of "bar" is an empty array. what's the thing that I do it wrong?

**update and answer:**

At last I found the reason that made the weird result. It's just a stupid mistake that I have made:

```
 // in directive "foo"
 controller: function($scope) {
    this.scope = $scope;
    // This line below is wrong. It is here 
    // because I transcompiled coffeescript to js.
    // return $scope.panes = [];
    // It should be like below:
    $scope.panes = []
    // I should have written .coffee like below
    // controller: ($scope) ->
    //     @scope = $scope
    //     $scope.panes = []
    //     return # prevent coffeescript returning the above expressions.
    //     # I should rather have added the above line
  }
```

After correcting the mistake, I tried and found there's nothing to prevent using controller or providing empty content in child directives.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot have a controller in the child directive.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/kv9udk4eB5B2y8SBLGQd?p=preview

```
app.directive('foo', [
   '$log', function($log) {
     return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div id="test" ng-transclude></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.panes = ['Item1','Item2','Item3'] 
        return { 
          getPanes: function() { return $scope.panes; }
        };
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        $log.log('test1', ctrl, ctrl.getPanes(), scope.panes);  
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

I removed the child controller.

```
app.directive('bar', [
  '$log', function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      require: '^?foo',
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.x = 1;
        $log.log('test2', ctrl, ctrl.getPanes(), scope.panes, scope.x);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: After debuggin for half a day, I removed the controller in child directive, and added some content to the child directive in html, like these: <bar> I'm a </bar>, and I got result I want.

Comment: I'm a SO newbie, and sorry for forgetting to say thanks in 5 minutes edit time :). Btw, Is it necessary that both child directive can not have controller and must be not empty when using required directive's controller as link's parameter? Is there any document mentioned this?

Comment: Sorry so much for the mistakes that I have made. The real reason is as below: function($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope;
        return $scope.panes = []; // should just "return;" or "return this;"} I made this mistake because the .js is translated from .coffee, and I forget adding a empty return statement at the end.